# Eclipse Che jumps to top when changing file tab

Tags: eclipse-che

When using Eclipse Che and switching between file tabs, each file always jumps to the top when switching back to that file tab.

Also, I have auto-save turned off but every time I save the "Save Star" reappears immediately (do not know if this is related).

Comment: I just tried it on 5.15.0 and Edge. I'm not see the same behavior you are.  I've seen a few funny things with different browsers.  Try a different browser and let us know.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce it (Ubuntu 17.04, Chrome 60, Eclipse Che 5.15.0). Both saving and jumping back to the last location after switching tabs work. Do you have an adblocker enabled that might interfere with some javascript functions?

Comment: It is strange as it is happening for one of our developers and not for others. Same client as above. I will look into chrome extensions on the affected client and report back.

Comment: Turned off all extensions on affected client, still happens (Ubuntu 14.04, Chrome 60, Eclipse Che 5.15.0). Switched to a fresh install of Firefox to test and issue persists!

Comment: Tried copying a file from the affected client to a non-affected client. The result reproduces the issue on all clients (so could be related to file size or something?) Weird thing is after deleting said file the issue persists in that workspace. To reproduce please use this standard magento file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View.php

Comment: Issue created on Eclipse Che github: https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/5850